# Serializing Typesafe Config objects

Tags: config, typesafe-stack

I'd like to persist a Config object (https://github.com/typesafehub/config) as a serialized string(maybe JSON ??) and read it back when required.  However, I didnt find any API on the Config api docs that supports.  Any help on this is appreciated.

I tried

```
config.toString
```

but the result looks like

Config(SimpleConfigObject({...data}))

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Try this:

```
config.root().render(ConfigRenderOptions.concise())
```

Comment: +1, and Java serialization is also supported, if that's better for a given application.

Comment: This also gives everything else besides my config in application.conf. so how can I json pretty print only the config from my application.conf?

Comment: @user1870400 if you really just want `application.conf` you can use `ConfigFactory.parseResourcesAnySyntax("application.conf")` - but this won't substitute any environment variables or system properties. You might look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195527/typesafe-config-load-additional-config-from-path-external-to-packaged-scala-app for some other options.

Comment: @user1870400 if you wrap everything in your `application.conf` in a top level object `myapp { ... }` you could do something like `ConfigFactory.load().getConfig("myapp").root().render( ... )`.

Answer (score 4):

Of course you can also adjust a few parameters, for example:

```
val renderOptions = ConfigRenderOptions
  .defaults()
  .setOriginComments(false)
  .setComments(false)
  .setFormatted(true)

println(config.root().render(renderOptions))
```