# Typesafe config: Load additional config from path external to packaged scala application

Tags: scala, configuration, app-config, config, typesafe-stack

My scala application will be packaged into a jar. When I run my app, it needs to read an additional config file stored externally to my app jar. I am looking for functionality similar to the Typesafe Config library but other solutions are welcome too ! Is there a way to do something like below:

```
val hdfsConfig = ConfigFactory.load("my_path/hdfs.conf")
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```
val myCfg =  ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File("my_path/hdfs.conf"))
```

Comment: This won't include reference.conf in the config; the canonical approach would be to sandwich the result of `parseFile` between the default reference config and the default overrides, which would look like `val fileConfig = parseFile(); val myConfig = ConfigFactory.load(fileConfig)`.

Comment: What `File` class is this? `java.io.File` or `scala.reflect.io.File`?

Comment: @EduardoBezerra, that is `java.io.File`

Comment: If we include other conf file inside the parseFile()'s parameter, can that also be read?

Comment: @WeiLin, I'm not sure I get what you mean.  Can you be more clear about what it is you are trying to do?

Comment: if file is located in dependency jar then what is the path to access?

Comment: @IrfanNasim That cnofig file may just be inside the classpath.

Answer (score 18):

If your external configuration is to add to or override configuration parameters from standard locations, you can do the following:

```
val baseConfig = ConfigFactory.load()
val config = ConfigFactory.parseFile(yourFile).withFallback(baseConfig)
```

where `yourFile` is a `java.io.File`
Documentation reference [here](https://github.com/typesafehub/config#merging-config-trees)

Answer (score 5):

```
val config = ConfigFactory.load("pathtoFile/FileName.propertes")
```

works, too.

Comment: I believe that only works if the file is on the classpath.

Comment: Indeed, this answer is more relevant to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32014502/5826349)